bot.edit_message_text не редактирует повторяющиеся сообщения
random_case_Revolution = {0:'Tec-9 | Rebel',1: 'P250 | Re.built',2: 'MAG-7 | Insomnia', 3:'SG 553 | Cyberforce', 4:'SCAR-20 | Fragments',
                            5: 'MP5-SD | Liquidation',6: 'MP9 | Featherweight',7: 'MAC-10 | Sakkaku',8: 'P90 | Neoqueen',9: 'Glock-18 | Umbral Rabbit',
                             10: 'R8 Revolver | Banana Cannon',11: 'M4A1-S | Emphorosaur-S',12: 'AWP | Doodle Lore',13: 'AWP | Duality',14: 'P2000 | Wicked Sick',
                               15: 'UMP-45 | Wild Child',16: 'AK-47 | Head Shot',17: 'M4A4 | Temukau'}
case_Revolution=random.choice(random_case_Revolution)
valu_list_case_Revolution=list(random_case_Revolution.values())
sample_case_Revolution=random.sample(valu_list_case_Revolution, k=17)

for _ in range(17):
            sleep(0.4)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = load_message1.message_id, text=sample_case_Revolution)

bot.edit_message_text не редактирует повторяющиеся сообщения
sample_case_Revolution берет 17 уникальных значение из листа random_case_Revolution, но видимо из-за цикла
 for _ in range(17):
            sleep(0.4)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = load_message1.message_id, text=sample_case_Revolution)

они все равно повторяются, как это можно починить?
